# How to find list of ODBC drivers installed on Linux

Tags: linux, odbc

Good day all.

On Windows, the list of installed ODBC drivers located here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers

On macOS, the list of installed ODBC drivers located here:
/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini and /Users/{userName}/ODBC/odbcinst.ini

The questions is: where could I find list of ODBC drivers installed in Linux?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks for the answers but I found out that list of installed ODBC drivers on Linux can be found on

/etc/odbcinst.ini and /home/{userName}/.odbcinst.ini which is very similar to macOS

Answer (score 31):

below command works for me in Unix.
It shows all the odbcinst.ini files

```
odbcinst -j
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. this will tell you how to find out which file to look for.

Answer (score 8):

The nicest tool to deal with all configuration-type stuff of UnixODBC is `odbcinst`.

From man page of `odbcinst`.

> odbcinst - An unixODBC tool for manipulating configuration files

It's a cool library that will ease your life a little while working in UnixODBC.
One of its options:

> ```
>    -j     Prints current configuration of unixODBC, listing (among others) the paths to the configuration files.
> ```

This is what you need.

E.g:

```
 # odbcinst -j

unixODBC 2.3.6
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Install it:

```
apt-get install odbcinst
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cat /proc/modules | grep odbc
```

or

```
lsmod | grep odbc
```

Comment: Not this kind of driver ...