# translate odbc::dbconnect to rodbc::odbcDriverConnect

Tags: r, database, odbc, rodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL database. It works via the RODBC package :

```
ch = odbcDriverConnect(paste0("DSN=mydns.net;database=MasterData;UID=user;PWD=pass"))

ch
RODBC Connection 1
Details:
  case=nochange
  DSN=mydns.net
  database=MasterData
  UID=user
  PWD=******
```

how could I make the connection using the odbc package ? the following does not work !

```
con = dbConnect(odbc(),
                   Driver = "MSODBC",
                   Server = "mydns.net",
                   Database = "MasterData",
                   UID = "user",
                   PWD = "pass",
                   encoding = "windows-1252",
                   Port = 1433)

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Brugeren 'user' kunne ikke logge p�.  [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute.
```

Also :

```
odbc::odbcListDrivers()
         name   attribute                                                   value
1  PostgreSQL Description                                     ODBC for PostgreSQL
2  PostgreSQL      Driver                                   /usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
3  PostgreSQL       Setup                                /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
4  PostgreSQL    Driver64                                 /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
5  PostgreSQL     Setup64                              /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
6  PostgreSQL   FileUsage                                                       1
7       MySQL Description                                          ODBC for MySQL
8       MySQL      Driver                                  /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
9       MySQL       Setup                                  /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
10      MySQL    Driver64                                /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
11      MySQL     Setup64                                /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
12      MySQL   FileUsage                                                       1
13    FreeTDS Description                                       FreeTDS for MSSQL
14    FreeTDS      Driver                                /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
15    FreeTDS       Setup                                   /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
16    FreeTDS    Driver64                                /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
17    FreeTDS     Setup64                                   /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
18    FreeTDS   FileUsage                                                       1
19    FreeTDS  UsageCount                                                       1
20     MSODBC Description                 Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
21     MSODBC      Driver /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.1
22     MSODBC  UsageCount                                                       1
```

Also I have tried the reverse process. For another database, I have an `ODBC` connection which is just working fine :

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                   Driver = "MSODBC",
                   Server = "D.ad009.win.org",
                   Database = "LCA",
                   UID = "LCA-User",
                   PWD = "xxxx",
                   encoding = "windows-1252",
                   Port = 1433)
```

If I use the concept of `RODBC` package and create someting like the `ch` :

```
ch = odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver=MSODBC;DSN=D.ad009.win.org;database=LCA;UID=LCA-User;PWD=xxxx"))
```

Also I'm getting the error as follow :

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver=MSODBC;DSN=D.ad009.win.org;database=LCA;UID=LCA-User;PWD=xxxx")) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 0, message [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied
2: In odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver=MSODBC;DSN=D.ad009.win.org;database=LCA;UID=LCA-User;PWD=xxxx")) :
  ODBC connection failed
```

So there is something I need to consider when I change from `ODBC` to `RODBC` and wise-versa.

Comment: The error `Brugeren 'user' kunne ikke logge` suggests that you are connecting just fine but your username/password are not allowed. Have you contacted your DBA for permissions verification? (I'm going to assume that you changed your real username to `'user'` for the sake of this question.)

Comment: yes. I have checked my user / pass. and in that error massage I just replace the real user name by 'user'. with the same authentication I'm able to connect via RODBC but not with ODBC package !

Comment: How are things going? No updates in a while.

Comment: @r2evans, No progress ! Just gave up ! the problem is also for the other way around as well : meaning I have an ODBC connection to another database, when I change it to RODBC I'm getting the error. I have added that one to the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

Your call to `RODBC` and `dbConnect` are not identical. In the former, you are accessing a "data source name" (DSN) that is named `"mydsn.net"`, whereas in the latter you are accessing a *server host* named `"mydsn.net"`. Find the `odbc.ini` (either in ~ or /etc) that is defining `[mydsn.net]` and see what other parameters are being used there that might give a clue to other parameters.

---

I think you need to update your `Driver=`, and the error message is a good hint at what it could be: `"ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server"`.

Ultimately, though, look for what the `odbc` package finds available on your system. On mine, this is what I find:

```r
subset(odbc::odbcListDrivers(), grepl("SQL Server", name))
#                             name        attribute value
# 1                     SQL Server         APILevel     2
# 2                     SQL Server ConnectFunctions   YYY
# 3                     SQL Server        CPTimeout    60
# 4                     SQL Server    DriverODBCVer 03.50
# 5                     SQL Server        FileUsage     0
# 6                     SQL Server         SQLLevel     1
# 7                     SQL Server       UsageCount     1
# 33 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server       UsageCount     1
# 34 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server         APILevel     2
# 35 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server ConnectFunctions   YYY
# 36 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server        CPTimeout    60
# 37 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server    DriverODBCVer 03.80
# 38 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server        FileUsage     0
# 39 ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server         SQLLevel     1
```

(Just use `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` yourself. I'm filtering it because there are many more on my system that would clutter the page.)

For me, I should use `Driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"`. (I could use `"SQL Server"`, but that driver is ... broken.) It looks like your system is defaulting to using version 13 of the driver; over to you if you want to stick with that or use a newer version available.

Also, the port needs to be added to the `server` component, as in `server="host,port"`. It defaults to 1433, so you can omit the argument entirely unless you are using a non-standard port.

This means you should be able to do something like

```r
con = dbConnect(odbc(),
                   Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                   Server = "mydns.net",
                   Database = "MasterData",
                   UID = "user",
                   PWD = "pass",
                   encoding = "windows-1252")
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion : `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found ` also running the  `subset(odbc::odbcListDrivers(), grepl("SQL Server", name))` returns nothing ! `[1] name      attribute value    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Comment: Remove the `subset` and just run `odbc::odbcListDrivers()`. I filtered it because my system has several other drivers available that distracted from the point.

Comment: However, when connecting to my SQL Server instance, I take this code above and change to my values (no arguments added or deleted) and it connects just fine. The error `file not found` is highly suspicious that something else (not R) is going on.

Comment: Have you tried `Driver="FreeTDS"` or `Driver="FreeTDS for MSSQL"` or `Driver="Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server"`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use directly the SQL Server driver:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
          Driver = "SQL Server",
          Server = "mydns.net",
          Database = "MasterData",
          uid = "user",
          pwd = "pass",
          encoding = "windows-1252",
          Port = 1433)
```

Comment: `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found`

Comment: I see, you'll need to install the SQL Server client for linux

Comment: but how then RODBC is able to establish the connection ?!

Comment: perhaps have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591242/13513328) to find the name of the drivers/connexions installed.

Comment: OK, sorry, didn't pay attention. So native SQL Server client isn't installed.

Comment: Could you please help me for installation ?

Comment: user9112767, have you [searched](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=install+microsoft+sql+server+odbc+driver)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server includes downloads for windows, linux, and macos for the most recent (17) version of the driver. The google search also includes downloads for older versions (such as [13.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339) and [11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434), if you need them).