# How to grab Postgres ODBC Driver version installed in a Linux Server?

Tags: linux, postgresql, odbc

I was trying to grab which odbc driver versions are installed in a linux server by listing the drivers in the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file and I noticed that the `DriverODBCVer` parameter is not available for the Postgres driver

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description =ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1
```

I already tried using lsmod and also fetch from /proc/modules with no success. I basically tried all the topics related to this other [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575855/how-to-find-list-of-odbc-drivers-installed-on-linux)

Is there any way to fetch the postgres ODBC driver that was installed in a linux server and currently configured to be used as a default? To give some context, One of processes (that returns the driver information) is giving us a different version from the one that should be installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the only way is to write a C program that calls the [`SQLGetInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetinfo-function?view=sql-server-ver15) function with `SQL_DRIVER_VER` as `InfoType`.

Here is a minimal program that works for me:

```c
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SQLHENV henv;
    SQLHDBC hdbc;
    char version[25];
    SQLSMALLINT version_size;

    (void) SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV,
                          SQL_NULL_HANDLE,
                          &henv);

    (void) SQLSetEnvAttr(henv,
                         SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
                         (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3,
                         0);

    (void) SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC,
                          henv,
                          &hdbc);

    (void) SQLGetInfo(hdbc,
                      SQL_DRIVER_VER,
                      &version,
                      25,
                      &version_size);

    write(1, version, strlen(version));
    write(1, "\n", 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I build and run it:

```
> gcc -Wall -o odbcversion -Wl,-rpath,/usr/pgsql-14/lib odbcversion.c /usr/pgsql-14/lib/psqlodbc.so
> ./odbcversion
13.02.0000
```

Comment: Can also be done from Python with `connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER)`

Comment: @GordThompson If you detail what Python modules are needed, that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Python we can use pyodbc's [.getinfo()](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#getinfo) method to retrieve the driver version (among many other things):

```py
import pyodbc

connection_string = (
    "DRIVER=PostgreSQL Unicode(x64);"
    "SERVER=192.168.0.199;"
    "UID=scott;PWD=tiger;"
    "DATABASE=test;"
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

print(cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER))
# 13.02.0000
```